# Allow users access only to their own data in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hierarchical-data, database, nosql

I'm trying to have a data structure like this and to ensure that a user can only pull in their own data, since all the processing is done client side.

What database security rules would I have to use so that User1 can access their own posts, but cannot access User2's posts?

(I'm using Firebase web)

**Sample database structure:**

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "001" : {
      "text" : "note 1",
      "userID" : "User1"
    },
    "002" : {
      "text" : "note 2",
      "userID" : "User1"
    },
    "003" : {
      "text" : "note 3",
      "userID" : "User2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample database query:**

```
firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // Returns all 3 posts
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your current structure it is very easy to secure data access to each post's creator:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$postid": {
        ".read": "data.child('userID').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is all that is needed: now each user can only read their own posts.

But there is one big problem with this approach: no-one can now read from `/posts`, so no-one can get a list of all posts.

And to grant someone the ability to list posts, you must give them read access to `/posts`. And since you cannot revoke a permission on a lower level, that means that you at that point they can read *all* posts, not just the ones they created.

This is known within Firebase as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters): you cannot use rules to filter data. We've covered it quite a bit here on Stack Overflow, so I recommend you also check out some [other questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

There are quite a few solutions to the problem.

#### Secondary index

A common solution is to create a list of the post IDs that each user has access to. This is often called a (secondary) index and adds this additional data to your model:

```
{
  "userPosts" : {
    "User1": {
      "001" : true,
      "002" : true
    },
    "User2": {
      "003" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Now you secure access to the original posts as before, but then secure access to the secondary index with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userPosts": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "$userid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So each user can read the list of postIDs they have access to, and can then read each individual post under `/posts/postID`.

#### Store each user's posts under a separate node

In your case, there is a simpler solution. I'd model that data slightly more hierarchical, with each user's posts under their own UID:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "User1": {
      "001" : {
        "text" : "note 1",
        "userID" : "User1"
      },
      "002" : {
        "text" : "note 2",
        "userID" : "User1"
      },
    },
    "User2": {
      "003" : {
        "text" : "note 3",
        "userID" : "User2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can secure access with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "$userid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And each user can read and list their own posts. But do keep the secondary index in mind, since you're likely to need it sooner or later.